# numeric progressive filename with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
|name     |code|
|---------|----|
|fa.st.pdf|10  |
|creed.txt|10  |
|logs.log |11  |
|log.s.txt|11  |  
|foo.bar  |11  |
```

what I need is to create a progressive filename for each code, like this:

```
|name |code|
|-----|----|
|1.pdf|10  |
|2.txt|10  |
|1.log|11  |
|2.txt|11  |  
|3.bar|11  |
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to enumerate the rows per group and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the file extension. Concatenate both as string:

```
df['name'] = (df.groupby('code').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
              + df['name'].str.extract('(\.[^.]+$)', expand=False)
              )
```

Output:

```
    name  code
0  1.pdf    10
1  2.txt    10
2  1.log    11
3  2.txt    11
4  3.bar    11
```